# Take URL from WebView when it did load. SWIFT

Tags: swift, macos, webview

How I can take URL from WebView in MAC OS(not IOS) when webView did load?

Help me please.

The same function have UIWevView - webViewDidFinishLoad. But I use WebView and I need take the url of page after page's loding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strVar = webView.request?.URL?.absoluteString

viewDidLoad not working. so use dispatch_async(GCD-Grand central Dispatch)